# Entity Framework 5 code first self referencing with extra attribute

Tags: entity-framework-5

Hi my problem is that when i run Add-Migration my database model end up like this. FK four times instead of two.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.IntressentIntressent",
            c => new
                {
                    ParentIntressentId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ChildIntressentId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Aktieantal = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Agare = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    Firmatecknare = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    Registreringsanmalan = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    FirmatecknareGeneralfullmakt = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    Revisor = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.ParentIntressentId, t.ChildIntressentId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Intressent", t => t.ParentIntressentId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Intressent", t => t.ChildIntressentId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Intressent", t => t.ParentIntressentId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Intressent", t => t.ChildIntressentId)
            .Index(t => t.ParentIntressentId)
            .Index(t => t.ChildIntressentId)
            .Index(t => t.ParentIntressentId)
            .Index(t => t.ChildIntressentId);
```

My classes look like this. if i remove fk statement in onmodelCreating EF will add it for me.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {   
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.IntressentIntressent>().HasKey(k => new
       {k.ParentIntressentId, k.ChildIntressentId });

       modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.Intressent>().HasMany(c => c.ParentIntressenter)
                   .WithRequired().HasForeignKey(cp => cp.ParentIntressentId);

       modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.Intressent>().HasMany(p => p.ChildIntressenter)
                   .WithRequired().HasForeignKey(cp => cp.ChildIntressentId);

   }
```

Entitys look like this

```
public class Intressent
{

    private ObservableCollection<IntressentIntressent> _parentIntressenter;
    public virtual ObservableCollection<IntressentIntressent> ParentIntressenter
    {
         get { return _parentIntressenter ?? (_parentIntressenter = new  
            ObservableCollection<IntressentIntressent>()); }
        set { _parentIntressenter = value; }
    }
}

public class IntressentIntressent
{
    [DisplayName("ParentIntressentId")]
    [Description("ParentIntressentId")]
    [Key, ForeignKey("ParentIntressent")]
    public int ParentIntressentId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ChildIntressentId")]
    [Description("ChildIntressentId")]
    [Key, ForeignKey("ChildIntressent")]
    public int ChildIntressentId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("ParentIntressent")]
    public Intressent ParentIntressent { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ChildIntressent")]
    public Intressent ChildIntressent { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Aktieantal")]
    [Description("Aktieantal")]
    public int Aktieantal { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicated the relation. In your `IntressentIntressent` you have used data annotations to define navigation properties and their related foreign keys. Then you have define fluent mapping for `Intressent` class but that mapping doesn't reflect those data annotations on opposite side of the relation. That result in defining relations twice. Replace fluent mapping with this:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.Intressent>()
               .HasMany(c => c.ParentIntressenter)
               .WithRequired(i => i.ParentInterssenter)
               .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.ParnetIntressentId);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Entity.Intressent>()
               .HasMany(p => p.ChildIntressenter)
               .WithRequired(i => i.ChildIntressent)
               .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.ChildIntressentId);
```

By defining opposite in `WithRequired` you pair those navigation properties to single relation.